# PatchValue in an angular subform made with ControlAccessValue cause parent form status to be Dirty

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building an app that uses nested form.

A nested form is a component that extends `ControlAccessValue` and speaks with the parent form through `onTouched` and `onChanged` function.

My problem is that when I patch a value in the SubForm the MainForm is marked as `dirty`. I would expect instead that both forms were dirty:false and pristine:true, that is actually what I would like to achieve.

I built a simple stackblitz to show you what I mean.

The question is: am I doing something wrong? Any help?

The example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b9twi8?

If you comment the line below you'll see that the parent form dirty value is set to `false`.

```
this.addressForm.get('street').setValue(this.streetValue);
```

Thank you all

Comment: This is expected behaviour as you subform changes a formcontrol on your main form (address)..?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest write `this.addressForm.get('street').setValue(this.streetValue, {onlySelf: true});` to prevent making dirty main form

Comment: This solution is not working..if you put onlySelf:true, the parent is not informed about child changes. I did some test and I found a solution. If you want to keep both parent and child status to {dirty:false, pristine:true} you have two solution.

First solution but not clean.. Invoke the function markAsPristine() in the Parent component inside ngAfterContentChecked 

Second solution is to put the form creation and initialization in the ngOnInit. I found that patch a value in the ngAfterViewInit for some reason change the parent form status to {dirty:true}..maybe is a life cycle problem.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose ngAfterViewInit controls already attached to component, after that all changes to values makes form dirty

Comment: The problem is that by definition a form is marked as dirty only when user change a value manually. https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#dirty 

A control is dirty if the user has changed the value in the UI.

Comment: Yeah but ui doesn't change value by magic it should call some methods for it e.g. setValue/pathcValue

Comment: @Rem According to the documentation post by @LucaT, the `dirty`/`pristine` attributes are set *if and only if the user changes the value from the UI*, that is, *by directly interacting with the UI*. In this example, however, the user does not interact with the UI and does not change anything manually and yet the form is marked as dirty nevertheless.